# Arabic not supported in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, arabic

I have this part of code that works fine only the arabic issue.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT login, password, name, role FROM qm_users WHERE login = '$login'");

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row["name"];
```

The `name` row contains arabic name.

The output of `echo` is `???? ???? ????`

In my myphpadmin of xamp server, here the structure

[image]

Comment: have you tried adding a header at the top before any out put with the correct oncoding i.e header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); and adjust to the correct charset

Comment: yes i ve added that: <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: no meta (html) is completely different to the header sent via php

Comment: Also, stop using the old and deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` and [prepared](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) [statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) + variable binding.

Comment: @Passerby well spotted completely overlooked that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to save UTF8 encodings to your MySQL database first set your connection encoding to UTF8.

```
<?php
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check below possible solution,

1) Your table structure 'Collation' must be 'utf8_unicode_ci'.

2) Also try to set below thing in php file

```
ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: worked perfectly.. logged in just to vote up.. :)